# Rerunning AsyncTask to refresh data, OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to restart my AsyncTask after 10 seconds to refresh the data. But I have some code but after a few seconds of executing the AsyncTask it throws an OutOfMemory Exception. What is the best way to handle this.

Here is my code:

**ASYNCTASK**

```
private class LoadQueueTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Queue>
    {

        @Override
        protected Queue doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Model model = Model.getInstance();
            return model.getQueue();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Queue result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adapter = new QueueAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.item_queue, result.getSlots());
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setEmptyView(empty);
            if(adapter.getCount() != 0)
            {
                callAsynchronousTask();
            }
        }

    }
```

**TIMER**

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                        try {
                            new LoadQueueTask().execute();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000);
    }
```

**ADAPTER**

```
public class QueueAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QueueSlots>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public QueueAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<QueueSlots> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_queue, null);
        }

        QueueSlots slots = getItem(position);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_title);
        TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_status);
        TextView category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_category);
        TextView mbsDownload = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_mbleft);
        TextView fileSize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_filesize);
        TextView persentage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_persantage);
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.queue_progressbar);

        title.setText(slots.getFilename());
        status.setText(slots.getStatus());
        category.setText(slots.getPriority() + " - " +slots.getCat());
        mbsDownload.setText(slots.getMb() - slots.getMbleft() + "MB");
        fileSize.setText(slots.getMb() + "MB");
        persentage.setText(slots.getPercentage() + "%");
        progress.setProgress(slots.getPercentage());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can post it if you want to take a look

Comment: Ok share it, but also isn't it an infinite loop at; if(adapter.getCount() != 0)
            {
                callAsynchronousTask();
            }

Comment: Its a long loop i know, but it also has a timer of 30000

Comment: @DevrimTuncer Yep it's solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part of your code at `onPostExecute` method:

```
if(adapter.getCount() != 0)
{
    callAsynchronousTask();
}
```

call `callAsynchronousTask` method once at some part of your code, for instance at `onCreate` method.

**Reason:** With your current implementation the first timer instance starts and executes an instance of `LoadQueueTask`. After execution is finished you are calling `callAsynchronousTask` again and it creates a new instance of a timer and this timer executes an instance of `LoadQueueTask` immediately. (Previous timer still waits for 10 seconds). So you are creating lots of timers and start them immediately after a `LoadQueueTask` finished and that causes an Out of memory exception(like an infinite loop).

**With my suggested edit:** You are going to create a single timer and it will execute `LoadQueueTask` every 10 seconds.